# Laravel Testing Fails with "... ReflectionException: Class config does not exist ..."

Tags: laravel, phpunit, config

I searched StackOverflow and the web tried everything I found out there to address the issue below to no avail.  The error only happens during phpunit testing. If run the Laravel application (php artisan serve) it works fine.

Here are the details:

I am on a Win7 running cygwin.  I am using a composer.json created in the php artisan create project.

```
Cygwin (win 7)
Runtime: PHP 7.4.8
PHPUnit 9.3.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Laravel Framework 7.26.0
```

Here is my composer.json which I think was initially created by "php artisan create project" or something like that.

```
$ cat composer.json
{
    "name": "rubens-gomes/rubens-gomes.com",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "rubens-gomes.com Web Site",
    "homepage": "https://rubens-gomes.com",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "PROPRIETARY",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rubens Gomes",
            "email": "rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://rubens-gomes.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.2"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": "@composer dump-autoload"
    }
}
```

Below is my phpunit.xml.  I tried the different bootstrap to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
  <!--  bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" -->
  bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
  colors="true"
  verbose="true">
  <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </include>
  </coverage>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

Here is the phpunit fatal error. I am not so much concerned with my test case failing below.  The main issue is the Fatal Error about "config not found ..."

```
$ php artisan test
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.


   PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ basic test


   FAIL  Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest
  ✕ fail to validate email

  Tests:  1 failed, 1 passed, 1 pending

  Failed asserting that exception of type "ErrorException" matches expected exception "Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException". Message was: "dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed" at D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\Validation\DNSCheckValidation.php:121 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\Validation\DNSCheckValidation.php:107 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\Validation\DNSCheckValidation.php:80 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd.php:65 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\EmailValidator.php:37 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes.php:666 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:547 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:370 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:401 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:444 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Factory.php:136 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider.php:58 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:111 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\app\Http\Controllers\ContactController.php:90 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest.php:43 .

  at D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\Constraint.php:121
    117|         if (!empty($description)) {
    118|             $failureDescription = $description . "\n" . $failureDescription;
    119|         }
    120|
  > 121|         throw new ExpectationFailedException(
    122|             $failureDescription,
    123|             $comparisonFailure
    124|         );
    125|     }

  1   D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\Constraint.php:55
      PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint::fail(Object(ErrorException), "")

  2   D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Assert.php:2331
      PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint::evaluate(Object(ErrorException), "")
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
Stack trace:
#0 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#3 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(637): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#4 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#5 D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C in D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 811
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main($exit = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
PHP   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run($argv = *uninitialized*, $exit = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:100
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run($suite = *uninitialized*, $arguments = *uninitialized*, $warnings = *uninitialized*, $exit = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:147
PHP   5. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run($result = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:671
PHP   6. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run($result = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:665
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run($result = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:665
PHP   8. Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest->run($result = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:665
PHP   9. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run($test = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:880
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->addFailure($test = *uninitialized*, $e = *uninitialized*, $time = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php:894
PHP  11. NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Phpunit\Printer->addFailure($testCase = *uninitialized*, $error = *uninitialized*, $time = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php:391
PHP  12. NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Phpunit\Style->writeError($state = *uninitialized*, $throwable = *uninitialized*) D:\gitprojs\php\rubens-gomes\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Phpunit\PrinterContents.php:114
```

Below is controller being tested.  Noticed that this is very basic code and testing just to see if things work.

And BTW I am learning Laravel.

```
$ cat app/Http/Controllers/ContactController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

/**
 * Controller to handle incoming "/contact" form requests.
 *
 * @author Rubens Gomes <rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com>
 * @copyright 2020 Rubens Gomes
 */
final class ContactController extends Controller
{

    /** @var array containing fields to be used on the view.*/
    private $data;

    /** @var array contact form validation rules. */
    private $formRules;

    /**
     *
     * @var \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha instance of Google ReCaptcha to be injected
     *      during unit testing. If no instance is injected a new one is created.
     */
    private $recaptcha;

    /**
     * The default constructor.
     *
     * @param ReCaptcha $rc The Google ReCaptcha object.
     */
    public function __construct(ReCaptcha $rc = null)
    {
        if ($rc === null) {
            $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptcha(config('services.recaptcha.secret_key'));
        } else {
            $this->recaptcha = $rc;
        }

        $this->data = [
            'pageId' => 'contact',
            'homeHref' => '/#home',
            'aboutHref' => '/#about',
            'contactHref' => '#contact'
        ];

        $this->formRules = [
            'email' => 'required|email:dns',
            'name' => 'required',
            'msg' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
        ];
        Log::debug(__CLASS__ . " constructed");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        Log::debug(__CLASS__ . " destructed");
    }

    /**
     * Process the incoming GET request to render the contact page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View The contact main page view.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        Log::debug(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__);
        return view('contact', $this->data);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the contact message form POST submit by validating the form
     * fields, validating the captcha and then sending an email message with
     * the information provided in the form.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *            The HTTP request
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View The contact main page view.
     */
    public function sendmsg(Request $request)
    {
        Log::debug(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__);
        // validate input contact fields
        Log::debug('validating contact form');
        $request->validate($this->formRules);

        // validate the captcha
        $captcha = $request->input(config('services.recaptcha.resp_parm'));
        Log::debug('validating captcha...');
        $response = $this->recaptcha->verify($captcha);

        if (! $response->isSuccess()) {
            Log::warning('failed to authenticate captcha');
            $captchaError = new MessageBag();
            $captchaError->add('recaptcha_error', 'Failed to authenticate captcha');
            return view('contact', $this->data)->withErrors($captchaError);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Your message has been successfully submitted.');
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/

// EOF
```

And here is my controller test code:

```
$ cat tests/Unit/app/Http/Controllers/ContactControllerTest.php
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Tests\TestCase;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

class ContactControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    /** @var \App\Http\Controllers\ContactController The controller being tested */
    private $controller;

    /** @var ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha The Google ReCaptcha being doubled */
    private $rcStub;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->rcStub = $this->createStub(ReCaptcha::class);
        $this->controller = new ContactController($this->rcStub);
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testFailToValidateEmail()
    {
        $this->expectException(ValidationException::class);

        $form = [
            'email' => 'rubens.s.gomes @ gmail.com',
            'msg' => 'This is a test.\nRubens Gomes',
            'name' => 'Rubens+Gomes',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'hello google captcha'
        ];

        $request = Request::create('/contact/sendmsg', 'POST', $form);
        $this->controller->sendmsg($request);
    }
}
```

Here is my .env file:

```
$ cat .env
APP_NAME="Laravel"
APP_ENV="local"
APP_KEY="base64:mJmYLlc2V43AKfa3u7s1po7RHyPDajRZIB4pIArTyjg="
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL="http://localhost"

LOG_CHANNEL="stack"

DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="laravel"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD="root"

BROADCAST_DRIVER="log"
CACHE_DRIVER="file"
QUEUE_CONNECTION="sync"
SESSION_DRIVER="file"
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST="127.0.0.1"
REDIS_PASSWORD="null"
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="smtp.mailtrap.io"
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME="null"
MAIL_PASSWORD="null"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="null"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="null"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
AWS_BUCKET=""

PUSHER_APP_ID=""
PUSHER_APP_KEY=""
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=""
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="mt1"

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

RECAPTCHA_DOMAIN="NOT_DISPLAYED"
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY="NOT_DISPLAYED"
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY="NOT_DISPLAYED"
RECAPTCHA_OWNER="rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com"
RECAPTCHA_VERSION="V2"
```

Comment: Can you please share your Controller & Controller Test code?

Comment: You can find a plenty of ideas [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/99)

Comment: I tried the "php artisan config:cache" suggestion on one of the github posts.  I saw an improvement (one less stack trace) in the phpunit.  But still having one case of "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in ...".  I have updated my initial post with the latest information on 08/27/2020.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on @depens tests. I cleared tearDown for fix it.

```
protected function tearDown() :void
{
    // Don't clear test environment between tests
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote all the code above.  And it is working fine now.  Below are portions of some of the new code.

composer.json:

```
$ cat composer.json
{
        "name" : "rubens-gomes/rubens-gomes.com",
        "type" : "project",
        "description" : "rubens-gomes.com Web Site",
        "homepage" : "https://rubens-gomes.com",
        "keywords" : [
                "framework",
                "laravel"
        ],
        "license" : "PROPRIETARY",
        "authors" : [{
                        "name" : "Rubens Gomes",
                        "email" : "rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com",
                        "homepage" : "https://rubens-gomes.com",
                        "role" : "Developer"
                }
        ],
        "support" : {
                "email" : "rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com"
        },
        "require" : {
                "php" : ">=7.4",
                "fideloper/proxy" : "^4.2",
                "fruitcake/laravel-cors" : "^2.0",
                "google/recaptcha" : "^1.2",
                "guzzlehttp/guzzle" : "^6.3",
                "laravel/framework" : "^7.24",
                "laravel/tinker" : "^2.0"
        },
        "require-dev" : {
                "facade/ignition" : "^2.0",
                "fzaninotto/faker" : "^1.9.1",
                "mockery/mockery" : "^1.3.1",
                "nunomaduro/collision" : "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "^8.5"
        },
        "config" : {
                "optimize-autoloader" : true,
                "preferred-install" : "dist",
                "sort-packages" : true
        },
        "extra" : {
                "laravel" : {}
        },
        "autoload" : {
                "psr-4" : {
                        "App\\" : "app/"
                },
                "classmap" : [
                        "database/seeds",
                        "database/factories"
                ]
        },
        "autoload-dev" : {
                "psr-4" : {
                        "Tests\\" : "tests/"
                }
        },
        "minimum-stability" : "dev",
        "prefer-stable" : true,
        "scripts" : {
                "post-autoload-dump" : [
                        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
                ],
                "post-root-package-install" : "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
                "post-create-project-cmd" : "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
                "post-update-cmd" : "@composer dump-autoload"
        }
}
```

phpunit.xml:

```
$ cat phpunit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  To run the unit tests configured in this PHPUnit XML configuration file:

       php artisan test -vvv

   @author Rubens Gomes <rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com>
   @link https://rubens-gomes.com
-->
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
  bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
  colors="true"
  verbose="true">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

.env:

```
$ cat .env
APP_NAME="rubens-gomes.com"
APP_ENV="testing"
APP_KEY="base64:mJmYLlc2V43AKfa3u7s1po7RHyPDajRZIB4pIArTyjg="
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL="http://localhost:8080"

LOG_CHANNEL="stdout"

MAIL_MAILER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="NOT_DISPLAYED"
MAIL_PASSWORD="NOT_DISPLAYED"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="NOT_DISPLAYED"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

RECAPTCHA_DOMAIN="rubens-gomes.com"
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY="NOD_DISPLAYED"
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY="NOT_DISPLAYED"
RECAPTCHA_OWNER="rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com"
RECAPTCHA_VERSION="V2"
```

test output:

```
$ php artisan test -vvv
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.


   PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ basic test




   RUNS  Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest
  • fail due to invalid form

  Tests:  4 passed, 17 pending
[2020-08-30T05:29:18.173039+00:00] testing.DEBUG: creating contact instance [] []

   RUNS  Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest
  • ensure sucess response for valid form


   PASS  Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\ContactControllerTest
  ✓ ensure request to index page works
  ✓ fails due to wrong resource
  ✓ fail due to post method not allowed for index page
  ✓ fail due to invalid form
  ✓ ensure sucess response for valid form



   PASS  Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers\HomeControllerTest
  ✓ ensure request to index page works
  ✓ fails due to wrong resource




   PASS  Tests\Unit\app\Mail\ContactRequestMailableTest
  ✓ fail due to null contact
  ✓ ensure constructor works
  ✓ ensure build works




   PASS  Tests\Unit\app\Mail\ContactResponseMailableTest
  ✓ fail due to null contact
  ✓ ensure constructor works
  ✓ ensure build works

   RUNS  Tests\Unit\app\Model\ContactTest
  • fail due to invalid email

   RUNS  Tests\Unit\app\Model\ContactTest
  • fail due to invalid email domain





   PASS  Tests\Unit\app\Model\ContactTest
  ✓ fail due to invalid email
  ✓ fail due to invalid email domain
  ✓ ensure contact is created
  ✓ ensure email is not empty
  ✓ ensure name is not empty
  ✓ ensure msg is not empty


   PASS  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ✓ basic test

  Tests:  21 passed
  Time:   4.93s
```

ContactControllerTest.php:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit\app\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;
use App\Mail\ContactRequestMailable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ContactControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    /** @var \App\Http\Controllers\ContactController The controller being tested */
    private $controller;

    /** @var ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha The Google ReCaptcha being doubled */
    private $rcStub;

    /** @var array valid post form data for testing purposes */
    private const VALID_FORM = [
        'email' => 'rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com',
        'msg' => 'This is a test.\nRubens Gomes',
        'name' => 'Rubens+Gomes',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'hello google captcha'
    ];

    /** @var array invalid post form data for testing purposes */
    private const INVALID_FORM = [
        'email' => 'rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com',
        'msg' => 'This is a test.\nRubens Gomes',
        'name' => '',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'hello google captcha'
    ];

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->rcStub = $this->createStub(ReCaptcha::class);
        $this->controller = new ContactController($this->rcStub, Mail::fake());
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testEnsureRequestToIndexPageWorks()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/contact/');
        $this->assertTrue($response->isOk());
    }

    public function testFailsDueToWrongResource()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/contact/hello');
        $response->assertStatus(404);
    }

    public function testFailDueToPostMethodNotAllowedForIndexPage()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/contact/');
        $response->assertStatus(405);
    }

    public function testFailDueToInvalidForm()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/contact/sendmsg', self::INVALID_FORM);
        $response->assertRedirect();
    }

    // unit testing controller
    public function testEnsureSucessResponseForValidForm()
    {
        $request = Request::create('/contact/sendmsg', 'POST', self::VALID_FORM);
        $rcResp = new \ReCaptcha\Response(TRUE);
        $this->rcStub->method('verify')->willReturn($rcResp);
        $this->controller->sendmsg($request);
        Mail::assertSent(ContactRequestMailable::class, 1);
    }
}
```

ContactController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\ContactRequestMailable;
use App\Model\Contact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

/**
 * Controller to handle incoming "/contact" form requests.
 *
 * @author Rubens Gomes <rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com>
 */
final class ContactController extends Controller
{

    /** @var array containing fields to be used in the view.*/
    private const VIEW_DATA = [
        'pageId' => 'contact',
        'homeHref' => '/#home',
        'aboutHref' => '/#about',
        'contactHref' => '#contact'
    ];

    /** @var \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail instance of mail service. */
    private $mailer;

    /** @var \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha instance of Google ReCaptcha. */
    private $recaptcha;

    /**
     * The default constructor.
     *
     * @param ReCaptcha $rc
     *            The Google ReCaptcha object.
     */
    public function __construct(ReCaptcha $rc = null)
    {
        if ($rc === null) {
            $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptcha(config('services.recaptcha.secret_key'));
        } else {
            // used during unit testing to inject a test double object
            $this->recaptcha = $rc;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process the incoming GET request to render the contact page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View The contact main page view.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact', self::VIEW_DATA);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the contact message form POST submit by validating the form
     * fields, validating the captcha and then sending an email message with
     * the information provided in the form.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *            The HTTP request
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View The contact main page view.
     */
    public function sendmsg(Request $request)
    {
        // validate and create contact
        $data = [
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'msg' => $request->input('msg')
        ];

        $contact = null;

        try {
            Log::debug('creating contact instance');
            $contact = new Contact($data['name'], $data['email'], $data['msg']);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
            Log::error('failed to create contact', $data);
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withException($ex)
                ->withErrors($ex->getMessage());
        }

        // validate the captcha
        $captcha = $request->input(config('services.recaptcha.resp_parm'));
        Log::debug('validating captcha', ['captcha' => $captcha]);
        $response = $this->recaptcha->verify($captcha);

        if (! $response->isSuccess()) {
            Log::warning('failed to authenticate captcha', ['captcha' => $captcha]);
            $captchaError = new MessageBag();
            $captchaError->add('recaptcha_error', 'Failed to authenticate captcha');
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($captchaError);
        }

        // send message by email
        Log::debug('sending email', ['email' => $contact->getEmail() ]);
        $reqMail = new ContactRequestMailable($contact);
        Mail::to($contact->getEmail())->send($reqMail);
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Your message has been successfully submitted.');
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/

// EOF
```

Contact.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

/**
 * A data model object to represent a contact (e.g., from the contact form).
 *
 * @author Rubens Gomes <rubens.s.gomes@gmail.com>
 */
class Contact
{

    /** @var array $validationRules The rules for validating input data */
    private static $validationRules = [
        'name' => 'required|max:100',
        'email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns',
        'msg' => 'required|max:1000',
    ];

    /** @var string $name The contact name */
    private $name;

    /** @var string $email The contact email address */
    private $email;

    /** @var string $msg The contact message */
    private $msg;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *            The non-blank contact name.
     * @param string $email
     *            The non-blank contact email.
     * @param string $msg
     *            The non-blank contact message.
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if any of the arguments is not valid.
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email, $msg)
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'msg' => $msg
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, self::$validationRules);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            Log::error("name or email invalid", $data);
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid argument: " . $validator->errors());
        }

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    public function getEmail() : string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getMessage() : string
    {
        return $this->msg;
    }

    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
/******************************************************************************/

// EOF
```

ContactRequestMailable.php:

````
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use App\Model\Contact;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

/**
 * Mailable used to send email of message in contact form.
 *
 * @author Rubens Gomes
 */
class ContactRequestMailable extends Mailable
{

    private const SUBJECT = "Rubens Gomes - Contact";

    /** @var Contact The contact instance. */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     *
     * @param Contact $contact
     *            the non-null and valid contact instance.
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if any of the arguments is not valid.
     */
    public function __construct($contact = null)
    {
        if (is_null($contact)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("contact cannot be null.");
        }

        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject(self::SUBJECT)
            ->locale('en')
            ->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
            ->to(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
            ->view('emails.contact-request')
            ->with([
            'name' => $this->contact->getName(),
            'email' => $this->contact->getEmail(),
            'msg' => $this->contact->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/

// EOF```
````